# org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException for Null @Version column

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions, jpa-2.0, optimistic-locking

I'm using Spring 3.0.4-RELEASE, JPA 2.0 with Hibernate as a provider, and JTA JOTM for transactions in my application.  I've received the following error when calling `entityManager.merge` on my entity object:

```
org.objectweb.jotm.SubCoordinator commit_one_phase
INFO: Rollback during beforeCompletion in SubCoordinator.commit_one_phase
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException 
      at
 org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1012)
```

This error came as a result of inserting data directly into the database (MySQL) through our Talend ETL job.  I noticed that my `@Version` column in the database had `NULL` values and decided to set them to 0 and this resolved the issue.

Why can't the `@Version` column be `NULL`?  Has anyone else come across this issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I've received the following error when calling entityManager.merge on my entity object

If you want to fully understand what is happening here, activate logging to see exactly what is resulting in the `RollbackException` (I suspect "bad" SQL).

Note that you aren't getting an `OptimisticLockException`, I think  that Hibernate is somehow getting confused by the `NULL` version. I didn't really dig the problem and can't explain it in details but it seems Hibernate isn't even generating the expected `UPDATE` statement for the merge.

> Why can't the @Version column be NULL? Has anyone else come across this issue? Thanks.

As I wrote, I can't give the exact reason but I'm tempted to answer: because that's not a value expected by Hibernate. Hibernate would start with `0` as initial value for the version column, my suggestion would be to respect Hibernate's expectation and set that as default value.

If you want to understand why setting `NULL` as initial value is causing troubles, you'll have to debug Hibernate's code. But honestly, this sounds like a waste of time: since you're using Hibernate, simply respect/mimic Hibernate's behavior when bypassing Hibernate's API.

Answer (score 0):

What behaviour do you expect?

When you perform `merge` on detached object, optimistic concurrency exception is thrown if version of the detached entity doesn't match version in the database. I guess in your case this exception is wrapped into `UnexpectedRollbackException`. If version of the detached entity is `0`, setting version column in the database to `0` solves this.

The real solution would be to increment version of the entity in the database when external software changes it. It would be consistent with optimistic locking strategy.